# Make child absolute within parent but not on page CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm at a project where I need all images within a div to be placed at the same place for an animation where I've put the images to be absolute to stack on top of each other though this interupts the rest of the code when scaling the page.

- Example start -

HTML

```
    <div class="a b">
         <div class="c d">
            <div class="e">
                <img class="f" src="" alt="image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="c d">
            Some content
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .a {
        clear: both;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%; }

    .b:before,
    .b:after {content:""; display: table; }
    .b:after {clear:both; }

    .c {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
        }

    .d {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 50%; 
        }

    .e {
        position: relative;
        margin: 100px auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 640px;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 640px;
        vertical-align: center;
        }

    .f {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
        }
```

- Example end -

As said this works great on fullscreen but when resizing the second class="c d"  appears overlapped by the first class="c d"  and I would like them to be stacked underneath eachother instead as the did before I created class="f", is there any way to do this with pure css?

Comment: can you please provide the HTML code

Comment: Fixed, must have deleted a blank row by mistake while writing

Comment: Use [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: @Vucko z-index change the z-axis, I need to affect the y-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. to make child absolute within parent you need to wrap the child with div with position relative.
2. for elements with position set to relative or absolute there is no direct way to prevent them from over layering, you can prevent them by calculating left and top values.
3. a work around is to use a blocking div. do that wrap your absolute positioned element with normal div and set its height to a value suitable to your needs check this plunker.

note the div with .absolute-parent class 
also note the div with .blocking-div class
check this plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/dT1cC8YAY1ENYfhRvncs?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Absolute Positioning</h1>

    <div class="absolute-to-page">
      to page
    </div>

    <div class="my-cont">
      <div class="blocking-div">
        <div class="absolute-parent">
          <div class="absolute-to-parent">
            to parent
          </div>
          <div class="absolute-to-parent obj-2">
            object two
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


        <div class="absolute-parent"> 
          <p>Some other content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Some other content 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

and the css code

```
/* Styles go here */

.my-cont{
  border:1px solid blue;
  min-height:400px;
  margin-top:200px;
}

.absolute-to-page{
  position:absolute;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:green;
  top:0;
}

.absolute-parent{
  position:relative;
}
.absolute-to-parent{
  position:absolute;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
  top:0;
}
.obj-2{
  left:50px;
}

.blocking-div{
  height:40px;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but I get sort of the same problem here, that the second .aboslute-parent gets in the same spot as the first one (overlayering)

Comment: can you please provide me with working plunker, I couldn't reproduce the issue

Comment: Not that sure about how plunker works but I forked it now with the additional <div>

        <div class="absolute-parent">
          <p>Some other content</p>
        </div> just underneatch the closing tag of the first absolute-parent

Comment: please give me the link of your plunker, after forking a plunker it gives you a new link.

Comment: That's how my code it the post act's as well when I'm looking at it from smaller screens, though it looks right on full screen

Comment: now I understand you problem. in short you if you set the position to absolute there is no way to prevent elements from over layering the only way is to calculate Top and Left properties. another solution is to wrap each element with its own div. check the above answer after editing.